# JQuery slideToggle function issue/how to

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm trying to use JQuery and slideToggle() to slide down a hidden row when it a particular header is clicked.  I'm trying to do this with 1 jQuery statement.  I know I can create an id for each div tag and have a separate function for each 'header row' that is clicked, but I would really like to NOT have to do this.

In the code example below I can only get the first row to do the slideToggle but I can't figure out how to get the other to slide when the 'header row' is clicked on.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
    $("#Content").slideToggle("slow"); /* Using this only toggles the first set of data */

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <div id="Label">
        1st Header:
    </div>
    <div id="Content">
        Data 1
        <br />
        Data 2
    </div>

    <!-- Row 2 -->
    <div id="Label">
        2nd Header
    </div>
    <div id="Content">
        Data 3
        <br />
        Data 4
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Duplicate `#Label` , `#Content` `id`s at `html` ? `id` of element should be unique within `DOM`

Comment: you have many elements with same id , the selector will select only the First catched one , so you should use Class , look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d76f9Lbj/)

```
<div>
    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <div class="Label">
        1st Header:
    </div>
    <div class="Content">
        Data 1
        <br />
        Data 2
    </div>

    <!-- Row 2 -->
    <div class="Label">
        2nd Header
    </div>
    <div class="Content">
        Data 3
        <br />
        Data 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".Label").click(function()
    {
        $(this).next().stop().slideToggle("slow"); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to accomplish is pretty simple and there are many ways to accomplish it.  Below is one easy way that relies on the header and content being in the order like you have above, but first don't ever create duplicate id's.  You want all id's to be unique for multiple reasons.

What you want to do is change it so the headers have one class and the content has another class.  https://jsfiddle.net/n1e7w5fL/1/

This is the html

```
    <div>
<!-- Row 1 -->
<div class="clickHeader">
    1st Header:
</div>
<div class="clickTarget">
    Data 1
    <br />
    Data 2
</div>

<!-- Row 2 -->
<div class="clickHeader">
    2nd Header
</div>
<div class="clickTarget">
    Data 3
    <br />
    Data 4
</div>
```

And this is the jquery to toggle them

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickHeader").on("click", function(){
        $(this).next(".clickTarget").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the link to JSFiddle.net.  That will end up being very handy!  And thank you for the code example too.